# Error: [News] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import "./Components/Font.css";
import News from "./Components/News";
import LoadingBar from "./Components/Loading";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer";

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    progress: 0,
  };
  setProgress = (progress) => {
    this.setState({ progress: progress });
  };
  apikey = process.env.REACT_APP_NEWS_API;
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <LoadingBar
              color="green"
              progress={this.state.progress}
              height={5}
            />
            <Navbar />
            {/* <h1>Hello</h1> */}

            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="general"
                  country="in"
                  category="general"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/ADP-Special">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="general"
                  country="in"
                  category="general"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/Science">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="science"
                  country="in"
                  category="science"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/Business">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="business"
                  country="in"
                  category="business"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/Entertainment">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="entertainment"
                  country="in"
                  category="entertainment"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/Health">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="health"
                  country="in"
                  category="health"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/Sports">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="sports"
                  country="in"
                  category="sports"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/Technology">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="technology"
                  country="in"
                  category="technology"
                />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/about">
                <News
                  setProgress={this.setProgress}
                  apikey={this.apikey}
                  key="general"
                  country="in"
                  category="general"
                />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my app.js code I have installed react-router dom version 6 and used routes instead of swicthes still i am getting this error. I also tried to put react.fragment under routes but still the error was not gone. Please help as I am new to react.

And don't read the next lines i copy paste the same lines because stackoverflow requires more lines and i don't have anything extra to say.

Here is my app.js code I have installed react-router dom version 6 and used routes instead of swicthes still i am getting this error. I also tried to put react.fragment under routes but still the error was not gone.

Answer (score 0):

Add element attribute in all `Route` components and pass the `News` component to it like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<News setProgress={this.setProgress}
               apikey={this.apikey}
              key="general"
              country="in"
              category="general"
            />}/>
```